# ERR 04120 TLS HANDSHAKE ERROR in Apache Directory Studio

Tags: ssl, macos-big-sur, tls1.0, apache-directory

I'm getting this error when i try to connect to a SSL (protocol v3) LDAP server in Apache Directory Studio.

I'm connecting to a LDAP server on port 636 (ldaps) with SSL encryption.

```
ERR_04120_TLS_HANDSHAKE_ERROR The TLS handshake failed, reason: Unspecified: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]
```

I'm using Apache Directory Studio Version: 2.0.0.v20210213-M16 on MacOS 11.2.3 (20D91)
java.version=16
java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc.

It seems that "some" update maybe disabled TLS1.0 on my mac???

Any clues how to fix this?

Comment: running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

So this may be a little late, but you need to follow the instructions [here](https://www.itechsol.com/openjdk-disables-legacy-tls-versions/).

An update to the JDK has disabled TLS1 and TLS1.1 support by default. You can change the defaults so they are no longer disabled.

Basically you need to find the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` property in `${JAVA_HOME}/conf/security/java.security` file and remove the offending algorithm from the list (`TLS1`).

Once you do this, you should be good to go.